# Dynamically adding nested loops

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, nested-loops

I have an 'X' amount of variables (likely to range between 3 to 20 options), which will be combined to calculate all possible combinations to meet a criteria. For every extra variable an extra loop is introduced, however I do not know if it possible to make the creation of loops dynamic (in excel VBA, the code doesn't have to be very fast).

To demonstrate:
I have var. A with h = 2, var. B with h = 3.
I would like to know all combinations which are equal to 10 or the best combination of the 2 variables.

In this case: option 1 = 5*A = 10, 3*B = 9,2*A and 2*B = 10, 3*A and 1*B = 9.

The code looks like this:

```
 For A = 0 to 5 
     h = 0 'Reset previous h if solution is found

   For B = 0 to 5

         h_test = A * height(A) + B * heigth(B)

          if h_test > 10
             if h = 0 then
               exit for
             else
               write h
               exit for
            end if

            h = h_test

  Next B
Next A
```

If another parameter is introduced (for example C = 4), the code is:

```
For A = 0 to 5 
     h = 0 'Reset previous h if solution is found

   For B = 0 to 5
     h = 0 'Reset previous h if solution is found

     For C = 0 to 5

       h_test = A * height(A) + B * heigth(B) + C * heigth(C)

       if h_test > 10
          if h = 0 then
            exit for
          else
            write h
            exit for
         end if

         h = h_test

      Next C
  Next B
Next A
```

In other words, I would like to know if it is possible to translate the pseudocode to real code:

```
For #parameter. = X

For loop1 = 1 to 5
   h = 0

   For loop2 = 1 to 5
       h = 0

     ....

        For loopX = 1 to 5

             h_test = loop1 *parameter1 + loop2 * parameter 2 ... 
                       + loopX * parameter X

            If h_test > 10
               Somecode
               exit for
            End if

        Next X
     ...
    Next loop2
Next loop1
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two distinct problems here. You didn't mention the first, and that is you also need to calculate a value with an indeterminate number of arguments. For that, you can use a `ParamArray`.

For example:

```
Public Function Sum(ParamArray args() As Variant) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim operand As Integer
    Dim result As Long

    For i = LBound(args) To UBound(args)
        result = args(i) + result
    Next i

    Sum = result
End Function
```

Which can be used and tested like this:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Debug.Print Sum(1,2)   '=> 3
    Debug.Print Sum(1,2,3) '=> 6
End Sub
```

So, that takes care of that problem. Now, as for the problem you asked about, we'll take a similar approach. The key is to loop once for each argument you've received.

```
Public Sub Run()
    NestedLoop 1, 2, 3

End Sub

Public Sub NestedLoop(ParamArray args() As Variant)
    Dim result As Long
    Dim a As Variant
    a = args

    Dim h_test As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    For i = LBound(args) To UBound(args)
        For j = 1 To 5
        result = 0
            h_test = Sum(a)

            If h_test > 10 Then
                If result = 0 Then
                    Exit For
                Else
                    Debug.Print result
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If

            result = h_test
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub


Public Function Sum(args As Variant) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim operand As Integer
    Dim result As Long

    For i = LBound(args) To UBound(args)
        result = args(i) + result
    Next i

    Sum = result
End Function
```

Comment: I do wish the downvoter would have explained themselves.

Comment: Dear RubberDuck, thank you for your quick and clear answer. It is a very clean solution, however I think it can not be adapted to my needs. This is because I want to know all possible combinations of parameters (incl. a multiplication) to best approach the criteria < 10. This is where the h_test = loop1 * parameter1 + loop2 * parameter2 .... + loopX * parameter X comes in. Your function SUM can only find the sum without the multiplications, and I am not sure if it is possible to adapt this to my needs (the h_test formula).

Comment: Paul, I'm not going to write the code for you, but you most certainly can use this approach given the question you asked. If you cannot, then your question is not an accurate representation of your real code.